# how to pass method of child as parameter to function in parent

Tags: c++, c++builder

In the following exceedingly abbreviated classes I would like to define in the base a method (ProcessLines) that would iterate over a set of database records, passing each record as a parameter to a function that is only defined in the child class. Obviously the Base is a virtual class that will never be instantiated on its own.

```
Class Base {
 public:
  typedef ProcLineFunc( Long *Line );
  void ProcessLines( ProcLineFunc pf);
}

Class Child{
  void DoWork( Long *Line) { //do something}
}
```

I'm not sure how to implement this. If I redeclare ProcessLines in the child and just call the parent method, I get the same error message as if I call ProcessLines in the code that creates the child.

```
Child c(//something);
c.ProcessLines(c.DoWork);
```

Gives me a compiler message:

> [BCC32 Error] main.cpp(67): E2034 Cannot convert 'bool (* (_closure )(long *))(long *)' >to 'int (*)(long *)'
>    Full parser context
>      main.cpp(56): class Add2Chan
>      main.cpp(78): decision to instantiate: bool Add2Chan::ProcessByLines()
>      --- Resetting parser context for instantiation...
>      main.cpp(67): parsing: bool Add2Chan::ProcessByLines()

I'm fairly new to c++ and the E2034 error message scares the daylights out of me.

Please help. I used a typedef so that I can, in my child classes call ProcessLines multiple times, passing in different functions as I go.

Comment: Unless I am missing something here, what you are attempting to do seems incredibly overcomplicated. Does it HAVE to work like this? I think there is scope to greatly simplify your design

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using pointers to functions, use pointers to objects. Accept the limitation that your function is going to be called `DoWork` and nothing else, and there can only be one such function in each class. This is not a bad limitation. Declare the (pure virtual) function in a class (which is called an *interface*), and derive classes from it (they are said to *implement* an interface).

```
struct DoingWork
{
    virtual void DoWork(long *Line) = 0; // does some work on a list
};

struct DoingGreatWork: DoingWork
{
    virtual void DoWork(long *Line) {printf("Great work\n");}
};

struct DoingSlightWork: DoingWork
{
    virtual void DoWork(long *Line) {printf("Slight work\n");}
};
```

Using this example:

```
class Base {
  public:
    void ProcessLines(DoingWork& object) {
        //Logic to process lines here
        while(moreLines) {
            object.DoWork(line);
        }
    }
};

class Whatever // no need to derive from Base
{
    void DoStuff()
    {
        Base object;

        object.ProcessLines(DoingGreatWork());
        object.ProcessLines(DoingSlightWork());
    }
}
```

If the working objects have to have access to the calling object, initialize them like this:

```
class Whatever // no need to derive from Base
{
    struct DoingElaborateWork: DoingWork
    {
        Whatever& caller;
        DoingElaborateWork(Whatever& caller): caller(caller) {}
        virtual void DoWork(long *Line)
        {
            printf("Doing work requested by %s\n", caller.name());
        }
    };

    void DoStuff()
    {
        Base object;
        object.ProcessLines(DoingElaborateWork(*this));
    }

    const char* name() {return "Whatever";}
}
```

P.S. They say that "in C++03 [functions are second-class citizens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function)" because you cannot do with functions what you can do with objects (like this solution i provide). I heard that in C++11 functions are much improved, but i am not sure about the details.

Comment: Thanks &anatolyg, this is very close to what I was looking for. Its still more complicated than I expected. The code I posted was derived from actual Delphi code I have been using for several years. In that case its called a 'method of object' and you are allowed to pass a method of one object to another function (in my case its just a standalone method) and call it from there, so long as the method prototype is known to both. cheers.

Answer (score 4):

Normally you would do this sort of thing with a protected, pure virtual function:

```
class Base {
  public:
    ProcessLines() {
        //Logic to process lines here, obviously psuedo-code
        while(moreLines) {
            ProcessLine(line);
        }
    }
  protected:
    virtual void ProcessLine(const Line& line) = 0;
}

class Child : public Base {
  protected:
    void ProcessLine(const Line& line) { //Logic to process the line for this type }
};

class DifferentChild : public Base {
  protected:
    void ProcessLine(const Line& line) { //Logic to process the line for DifferentChild }
};
```

I think this is the kind of thing you're looking for. It appears to me like you're trying to implement polymorphism in an odd way, but this is the normal way to do it in C++.

Comment: There is nothing special about `protected`, the pure virtual function can be `public` or (better) `private`

Comment: I didn't implement it this way because in some cases I will have to have several ProcessLine methods in a class and call ProcessLines for each of them, so I'm trying to make it as general as possible. The base class is actually a wrapper around an API and may end up having dozens, or hundreds, of child classes defined over time.

Comment: @anatolyg Thanks for the note. I figured he didn't want users of this class to be able to call the single function, butI guess you never know

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this in C++Builder, you can utilize its `__closure` extension to do exactly what you asked for (some portions of the VCL do exactly this for their own callbacks):

```
class Base
{ 
public: 
    virtual ~Base() {}

    typedef void (__closure *ProcLineFunc)( Long *Line ); 
    void ProcessLines( ProcLineFunc pf); 
}; 

class Child : public Base
{ 
public:
    void DoWork( Long *Line) { //do something} 
}; 

Child c(...); 
c.ProcessLines(c.DoWork);
```